# Merging code in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, merge

I am currently developing .NET code and am using VS2010. One thing I struggle with is merging code. The built in merging software seems like it should be a snap to use but I am unable to find out how to use it well. Does anyone have any pointers or know any open source merging software that would be beneficial to use?

Comment: What problems are you having? What exactly are you finding difficult with the merge tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might take a look at this post on using WinMerge with Visual Studio http://www.neovolve.com/post/2007/06/19/using-winmerge-with-tfs.aspx, it's a little out dated but should tell you what you need to know